# How to use cv2.waitKey(1) in Python OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am doing some `OpenCV` python code and I have below code at the end:

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

So whenever I press `q`, the code breaks which is working fine. But below code is not working:

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('a'):
    print('a')
```

In above code, only `q` is working but if I press `a`, it is not printing `a`. Why is this not working. Can anyone please suggest me what is wrong here. Thanks

CODE:

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret_val, image = cam.read()

    cv2.imshow('my webcam', image)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('a'):  
        print("a")
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Putting these two lines in some `while True:` loop after some `cv2.imshow(...)`, I can achieve the desired behaviour. Please provide a [mre], so that people here can further investigate your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

waitKey returns the ASCII value of key that's pressed while ord converts a character into its ASCII value. So something like this will work

```
key = cv2.waitKey(1)
if key == ord('q') :
 break
elif key == ord('a'):
 print('a')
```